# For Loop never executing (Javascript / Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

So the for loop runs if I replace`$.get('/preceed_with_an.txt', function(data){var ans = data.split('\n')});` with `ans = ["filler","more filler"]` but when the $.get line is in it refuses to execute the for loop and nothing is ever written to the console. For context, I am writing code that tells you if you should use A or AN before a word. Words that you use an for are all on separate lines in `preceed_with_an.txt` I have checked an the $.get functions and the file is written to the array just fine.

```
$(document).on('input',$('#givenWord'),function(){
      var ans = new Array;
      $.get('/preceed_with_an.txt', function(data){var ans = data.split('\n')});  
 for (var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++){
    console.log("help");
    if (ans[i] == $('#givenWord').lower){
      var answer = $("#answer");
      console.log("AN");
      $(answer).text("An");
      break;
    }else{
      var answer = $("#answer");
      console.log("A")
      $(answer).text("A");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get()` is asynchronous, so ans.length is equal to zero because the data return after the for loop execution.

You have to execute the `for` loop in the `get()` callback function:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
   var arr = data.split(',');
   for(...) {
      //...
   }
});
```

**Execution flow (your code)**

1. Create ans array
2. Call the `get()` function
3. Try to execute the `for` loop (without available data)
4. `get()` return the data

**Asynchronous call**

1. Create ans array
2. Call the `get()` function with the `for` loop in the callback
3. `get()` returns data and executes the callback --> for loop with data

**EXAMPLE**

Check the console for the results. Even if the setTimeout function is called before the console.log(), the code continued the execution and waited for the callback's answer (after 1 second). When the result came out, the callback executed:

```js
var def = $.Deferred();

def.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

//Asynchronus call (delays for 1 second)
setTimeout(function() { 
  def.resolve('Callback after 1 second') 
}, 1000);

//Execute immediately
console.log('Write something!');

//Console results
// 1. Write something
// 2. callback (after 1 second)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check these links about asynchronous functions:

[jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

[Async](http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/)